# SQLite insert statement always overwrite existing row

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a simple insert SQLite statement :

```
private final String INSERT_FEED = "insert into "
        + TABLE_FEEDS
        + "([id],[first_name], [last_name], [image], [content]) "
        + "values (?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Which i used in a method :

```
public long insertFeed(FeedsModel feed) {

this.insertStmt = db.compileStatement(INSERT_FEED);
this.insertStmt.bindString(1, feed.getId() + "");
this.insertStmt.bindString(2, feed.getFirstName());
this.insertStmt.bindString(3, feed.getLastName());
this.insertStmt.bindString(4, feed.getProfileImage());
this.insertStmt.bindString(5, feed.getContentDetails());

long result = this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
return result;
}
```

Later, i used that method in my activity :

```
            for(int i = 0; i < feedsAdapter.getCount() - 1; i++)
            {
                helper.insertFeed(feedsAdapter.getItem(i));
            }
```

The problem is, the table always have only 1 row because the new data will overwrite the existing row, instead of inserted in a new row.

Comment: what does this statement return? `feedsAdapter.getCount() - 1`

Comment: @Siva it returned 11 items

Comment: maybe the query showing the sqlite table has a problem ??

Comment: **1** - You shouldn't insert the id value, if it's an autoincrement field. **2** - why `feedsAdapter.getCount() - 1`? remove `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your current for loop is inserting all the FeedsModels other than the last one. If you only have one model in the list it would explain why you are not seeing any new inserts into the table, instead do:

```
for (FeedsModel feedsModel : feedsAdapter) {
    helper.insertFeed(feedsModel);
}
```